# Setting up a method to be called by a TextChangedListener

Tags: java

-EDIT 5/27/2020-

I've advanced a little further with my code and now i'm trying to get the cost to update with the onTextChangedListener. It seems to be doing it's job however it always uses the int 0 for every value even after its changed and you can see the value being "refreshed". I'm hoping there's something wrong in my code that I'm not catching. I look forward to everyones input.

```
        final Button bContinue = findViewById(R.id.bContinue);
        final EditText etHamburger = findViewById(R.id.etHamburger);
        final EditText etHotdog = findViewById(R.id.etHotdog);
        final EditText etDrink = findViewById(R.id.etDrink);
        final EditText etSpecialInstructions = findViewById(R.id.etSpecialInstructions);
        final EditText tvCost = findViewById(R.id.tvCost);

        etHamburger.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int Hamburger;
                try {
                    Hamburger = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etHamburger));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Hamburger = 0;
                }
                int Hotdog;
                try {
                    Hotdog = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etHotdog));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Hotdog = 0;
                }
                int Drink;
                try {
                    Drink = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etDrink));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Drink = 0;
                }
                int cost = Hamburger + Drink + Hotdog;
                String message = "Total Cost $ " + cost;
                tvCost.setText(message);
            }
        });
        bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent OrderIntent = new Intent(order.this, ContactInfo.class);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHamburger", String.valueOf(etHamburger));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHotdog", String.valueOf(etHotdog));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etDrink", String.valueOf(etDrink));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etSpecialInstructions", (Parcelable) etSpecialInstructions);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("tvCost", (Parcelable) tvCost);
                order.this.startActivity(OrderIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-ORIGINAL QUESTION AND CODE-

I'm having trouble getting this code to work and I've been searching for a solution but I can't seem to find one. Here's a look at my code. I'm just trying to get it so my TextChangedListener activates a method to recalculate the total after the user changes a quantity. I've searched other posts to find my answer and didn't see what I was looking for but I'm also new to this. Currently I'm having trouble creating the method, my TextChangedListener seems to be working.

```
package com.example.foodordering;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.GetChars;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class order extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);


        final Button bContinue = findViewById(R.id.bContinue);
        final EditText etHamburger = findViewById(R.id.etHamburger);
        final EditText etHotdog = findViewById(R.id.etHotdog);
        final EditText etDrink = findViewById(R.id.etDrink);
        final EditText etSpecialInstructions = findViewById(R.id.etSpecialInstructions);
        final EditText tvCost = findViewById(R.id.tvCost);


        public void calculate(){

            int Hamburger;
            try {
                Hamburger = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etHamburger));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Hamburger = 0;
            }
            int Hotdog;
            try {
                Hotdog = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etHotdog));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Hotdog = 0;
            }
            int Drink;
            try {
                Drink = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etDrink));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Drink = 0;
            }
            int cost = Hamburger + Hotdog + Drink;
            String message = "Order Total $" + cost;
            tvCost.setText(message);
        }

        etHamburger.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                calculate();
            }
        });
        bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent OrderIntent = new Intent(order.this, ContactInfo.class);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHamburger", (Parcelable) etHamburger);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHotdog", (Parcelable) etHotdog);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etDrink", (Parcelable) etDrink);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etSpecialInstructions", (Parcelable) etSpecialInstructions);
                order.this.startActivity(OrderIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution!

Changed the message forumla to add together double values instead of intergers and added in exception catcher so null = 0 instead of null.

You can compare this code to the initial question code to see the changes.

This basically auto updates the total quantity as you make changes to the EditText boxes allowing for instant updates.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
package com.example.foodordering;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class order extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        final Button bContinue = findViewById(R.id.bContinue);
        final EditText etHamburger = findViewById(R.id.etHamburger);
        final EditText etHotdog = findViewById(R.id.etHotdog);
        final EditText etDrink = findViewById(R.id.etDrink);
        final TextView tvCost = findViewById(R.id.tvCost);
        final EditText etSpecialInstructions = findViewById(R.id.etSpecialInstructions);

        etHamburger.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                calculate();
            }
        });
        etHotdog.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                calculate();
            }
        });
        etDrink.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                calculate();
            }
        });
        bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent OrderIntent = new Intent(order.this, ContactInfo.class);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHamburger", String.valueOf(etHamburger));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etHotdog", String.valueOf(etHotdog));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etDrink", String.valueOf(etDrink));
                OrderIntent.putExtra("etSpecialInstructions", (Parcelable) etSpecialInstructions);
                OrderIntent.putExtra("tvCost", (Parcelable) tvCost);
                order.this.startActivity(OrderIntent);
            }
        });
    }
    private void calculate(){
        final EditText etHamburger = findViewById(R.id.etHamburger);
        final EditText etHotdog = findViewById(R.id.etHotdog);
        final EditText etDrink = findViewById(R.id.etDrink);
        final TextView tvCost = findViewById(R.id.tvCost);

        String etHamburgerStr = etHamburger.getText().toString();
        String etHotdogStr = etHotdog.getText().toString();
        String etDrinkStr = etDrink.getText().toString();
        double etHamburgerDbl;
        try {
            etHamburgerDbl = Double.parseDouble(etHamburgerStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            etHamburgerDbl = 0;
        }
        double etHotdogDbl;
        try {
            etHotdogDbl = Double.parseDouble(etHotdogStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            etHotdogDbl = 0;
        }
        double etDrinkDbl;
        try {
            etDrinkDbl = Double.parseDouble(etDrinkStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            etDrinkDbl = 0;
        }
        double cost = (etHamburgerDbl + etDrinkDbl + etHotdogDbl);
        String costmessage = "Total Cost $" + cost;
        tvCost.setText(costmessage);
    }
}
```